# Curve with polar coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have the function in polar form

[image]

And I want to draw it, and the unit circle (also in polar coordinates), use `ginput` to mark start roots and then use `fzero` to calculate the intersections. I've started by plotting both graphs, but how should I implement `ginput` and `fzero` to get my points of intersection?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
a=2+sin(3*t);
b=1+exp(cos(t));
r=@(t)a./sqrt(b);
plot(t,r(t));
hold on
r=@(t)sqrt((sin(t)).^2+(cos(t)).^2);
plot(t,r(t));
hold off
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`PolarPlot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html)?

Comment: Please avoid to ask multiple questions at once: (1) plot in polar coordinates, (2) use `ginput` and (3) use `fzero`.